# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot drop database . How to resolve?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I have added a property "password" in my class model User. It's showing in my view `Register.cshtml` now.

```
 <form action="~/Users/SaveRegister" method="post">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
    </form>
```

But it's giving the exception in my controller `db.Users.Add(User);` when I press `Register`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SaveRegister(Airlineapp.Models.User User, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    db.Users.Add(User);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire exception message

Comment: BTY why do you have two form tags? <form action="~/Users/SaveRegister" method="post">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: Cannot drop database "AirlineappContext-20180224010232" because it is currently in use. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot drop database "AirlineappContext-20180224010232" because it is currently in use.

Comment: It seems you have some pending database migration to run..

Comment: Are there any before filters attached to the controller actions?

Comment: No there are not filter attached to the controller action yet.

Comment: If you are following code-first approach, try migrating the database and see if that works.

Comment: The posted code won't throw that exception, so please read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: It is resolved now. Thank you

Comment: Under no circumstances do you ever store a password in a database as plain text! You need to hash and salt it. I suggest you go to the MVC site and work though the tutorials on Security, Authorization and Authentication.

Comment: you could upvote the comment/response that resolved this for you...  if there isn't one, post a new answer with your solution in order to help developers with the same issue in the future

Comment: I have upvoted. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone connected to the database. Try to switch to another database and then, to drop it:

Try

`SP_WHO` to see who connected

and `KILL` if needed or use `using (context db = new context())`